# How to send bamboo variables from Bamboo script to docker container?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, continuous-integration, bamboo

I'm using Docker plugin for bamboo and I need to execute a script in the docker container.

The sh script contains:

```
echo \"ini_source_path\": \"${bamboo.ini_source_path}\",
```

and if I put this line directly in Container Command, the ${bamboo.ini_source_path} will be replaced with value of this variable.

The problem in when I put /bin/bashscript.sh in Container Command because I'm getting a error:

```
script.sh: line 35: \"${bamboo.ini_source_path}\",: bad substitution
```

Is there a way I can reach bamboo.ini_source_path variable from my script in docker container?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to pass it as environment variable to container?

Comment: No, I've got too many variables, hoping I'll be able not to have to pass each one to container.

Comment: Can you vote up if my answer help you?thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Bamboo are you using? This problem was fixed in Bamboo 6.1.0:

[Unable to use variables in Container name field in Run docker task](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-18282)

**Workaround:**

- Create a Script Task that runs before the Docker Task.
- Run commands like

  ```
  echo "export sourcepath=$ini_source_path" > scriptname.sh
  chmod +x scriptname.sh
  ```

The Docker Task will be map the ${bamboo.working.directory} to the Docker \data volume.

So the just created scriptname.sh script is available in the Docker container.The script will be executed, and will set the variable correctly.